# Kinesis CMK manual rotation - can I assign alias to stream and rotate key manually every month?

Tags: amazon-web-services, key, amazon-kinesis

I'm missing or misunderstanding something...
I created a Kinesis data stream and configured it to use a CMK with an alias name: `kdskeyalias`. The CMK was assigned KeyID 31c1...e95e1.

I then generated a new key 2437...83b75 and updated the alias to point to it.

When I list aliases it looks correct. The alias name is pointing to the new keyid. However when I view the stream configuration the encryption setting still points to the original keyid: 31c1...e95e1.

Is there a way I can configure the stream to use the alias so I can manually rotate the key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used console, **key ARN** will be used when you select it from the drop down list, not the key's alias ARN.

You can **verify** that by using [describe-stream](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/kinesis/describe-stream.html) AWC CLI call.

If you do this, you should see following **key ARN** (example):

> arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:123456789012:**key**/12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012

For **key alias ARN** it would be (example):

> arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:123456789012:**alias**/MyAliasName

To specify the Alias ARN, you can use [start-stream-encryption](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/kinesis/start-stream-encryption.html) AWS CLI.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was exactly what I was looking for. If it were a snake it would have bit me.